# Errno 99 Cannot assign requested address Request Method: POST Request URL

Tags: python, django, api, http, djangorestframework

Obtengo el siguiente error al realizar un registro de usuario en django-rest-framework haciendo uso de la ruta /rest-auth/registration/

**[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address Request Method: POST Request URL: http://104.42.33.211/rest-auth/registration/ Django Version: 1.11.2 Python Executable: /usr/local/bin/python**

El servicio del API se esta ejecutando por el puerto 80 de un contenedor Docker alojado en un servidor Linux en Microsoft Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega lo siguiente al archivo de configuración de Django (settings.py) para que sea opcional la verificacón por correo:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
```

o agrege un Backend para la gestión del servidor SMTP:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: Super, asi funciona, muchas gracias